# Javascript spread syntax merges in object but appends in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, functional-programming

I have a weird situation. I have 2 objects: `state.result` which is an array of objects and `data.catalogs` which is an array of objects similar to `state.result`.

I want to create a pure function to return copy of both of them merged (in a redux reducer). If I run:

```js
 {
    ...state,
    result: {...state.result, ...data.catalogs}
  }
```

Everything is hunkey dorey and the 4 items in state.result are merged with the 1 item in data.catalogs leaving me with a return value of 4 items. The problem is I want an array of items and this gives me and object with 4 properties containg the items.

If I run:

```js
  {
    ...state,
    result: [...state.result, ...data.catalogs]
  }
```

It gives me an array of items like I want but instead of merging them, it appends them so I get an array of 5 items (a duplicate of the item in state.result and data.catalogs).

Why is this happening and how can I merge items within an array?

Comment: I didn't get.. `state.result` contains only `data.catalogs` ? Show how your state looks like ( the relevant part )

Comment: Oh sorry state is empty right now

Comment: Array spead operation can not merge, because it has no keys to merge with. You can check out Dan Abramov's tutorial on working with array in reducers here: https://github.com/RyoIkarashi/redux-tutorial-by-dan-abramov/blob/master/05-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat()-slice()-and-spread.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to handle merging of arrays separately

```
const x = [{id: 1}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}, {}];
const y = [{name: 'one'}, {}, {id: 3, name: 'three'}];

const z = x.map((e, index) => Object.assign({}, {...e, ...y[index]}));

// z = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}, {id: 3, name: 'three'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    {
    ...state,
    result: {...state.result, ...data.catalogs}
  }
```

How about using that then taking the values you want out of it with `Object.values(results)` you can `.map()` it if you need to as well.

I hope that helps.